# What does "The default initialization of any object happens-before any other actions (other than default- writes) of a program" mean?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

Java Language Specification 7, section 17.4.5:

```
5. The default initialization of any object happens-before any other
actions (other than default-writes) of a program.
```

What does it exactly mean? What is default initialization? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Which part of that description isn't clear?

Comment: What is default initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default initialization is process of assigning the instance's fields to [their respective default values.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

That section you've quoted tells you this happens before, for example, the constructor is called.

Comment: Ok, it appears to be very easy. I thought it was something related to `final` fields

Comment: Interestingly, I don't see an explicit definition of the phrase in the JLS.

Comment: What is "default-writes" here? How is "default-writes" different from "default initialization"?

Answer (score 2):

Happens-before is a concurrency term. At face value, it means what you think, but it goes beyond that.  For non-final, non-volatile fields, Java doesn't guarantee that the field values will by synced across threads unless something establishes a happens-before relationship.

That part of the spec means that other threads accessing the object will see the default initialization values, even if you spawn a thread in the constructor.